# tomcat 5.5.20 on geoserver 2.3

Tags: geoserver, java, error, tomcat

I know it is curious, but I want to run GeoServer 2.3.0 on Tomcat 5.5.20. When I deploy the war file it deploys successful but I can't start the GeoServer.

Message:

FAIL - Application at context path /geoserver_2.3.0 could not be started

Unfortunately I must use Tomcat 5.5 and until GeoServer 2.1.4 I can deploy and start fine.

You know how can I solve this or you have any experience.

Comment: what's in the error log?

Comment: ERROR [3.0]] - Error configuring application listener of class org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerHttpSessionListenerProxy
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)....

Answer (score 1):

I recall that geoserver 2.3 wants java 1.6 up, maybe your tomcat is using an older version.

Comment: this can be possible. I see my tomcat 5.5 use jvm Version: 1.5.0_17. You know how can i change this.

Comment: edit JAVA_HOME to point to a newer JVM

Comment: i set the environment variables java_home and edit the setenv.bat to the right path to jdk1.6.0. Catalina.bat JAVA_HOME use the %JAVA_HOME%. When i restart tomcat the jvm Version is still using 1.5 java version

Comment: @aykon How do you start tomcat? Are you on linux or win? Try to restart the console (start a new session if you are on linux); it's also possible that the JAVA_HOME defined for the user which runs tomcat points to the old java version

Comment: tomcat automatically starts when i starting den windows server 2003 system(64 bit).

I set the JAVA_HOME on the new java Version, but how or where  can i check the user which runs tomcat points to the old java version or what exactly do you mean.